# Meaning of two points after object (..) in method calling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Whats the meaning of the two points in the following code snipped?

```
@collection = @collection.where(end_time: DateTime.now..)
```

Comment: It's an endless range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [endless range](https://bigbinary.com/blog/ruby-2-6-adds-endless-range), first introduced in ruby version `2.6`. You can see the latest documentation on the language feature [here](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Range.html#class-Range-label-Beginless-2FEndless+Ranges).

As with all ruby code, a good way to understand small snippets is to paste them into a REPL such as `pry` or `irb` to see the result:

```
DateTime.now..
  => Fri, 11 Jun 2021 14:29:09 +0000..
```

---

So in your particular case, the code:

```
@collection.where(end_time: DateTime.now..)
```

is a fancy way of saying saying "collection where `end_time >= DateTime.now`". You should see this reflected in the generated SQL statement.

Comment: `Fri, 11 Jun 2021 14:29:09 +0000..` might still be confusing if you don't know what the trailing `..` means. You probably have to inspect the the object's class to understand it.